# Safari 10.0.3 is not downloading csv.

Tags: css, download, safari

I have a link that should allow the user to download a csv file.

The follow code is working for chrome browsers.

```
<a href="path/myfile.csv">
```

Wen I try to do the same for Safari 10.0.3 (desktop) it redirects to the csv page, not download it.

I think I can not use the `download` attribute since it works only for Safari 10.1 +, based on [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp) info.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Update your safari browser to the latest version. 10.0.3 does not support the HTML5 attribute `download = "#"`

I.E.

This will not work in Safari 10.0.3, for this version does not support HTML5 attributes.